# Make all links within an element load new content into that same element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery

This is a question about jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = $(this).attr('href');

        location.hash = link;

        $('#content').load(link);
    });
});
```

When I click on a link, the `#content` div is loaded with the page and the name with a hashtag is appended to the URL.

But I want every page inside the `#content` div, loaded by jQuery to do the same. It is only working for the original content.

Now I have this:

```
$('#content a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    location.hash = link;
});
```

Example:

I have donate.php loaded by jQuery into `#content` div, and when I click on a link on the donate.php, it should load new content into the `#content` div.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: please mark an answer to complete this post.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *event delegation*. Since the `#content` element itself is not loaded dynamically and you are wanting to target the `a` elements within that. It probably makes most sense to delegate on the `#content` element. Try this:

```
$('#content').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    location.hash = link;
    $('#content').load(link);
});
```

This way, it will work even if the anchor element was added dynamically. You can read more about that on the [`.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), search for delegated events.

---

To explain this further, the above solution using delegation is basically saying "if there is a click within `#content`, check if the click was within an `a` element." So this will work whether or not that `a` element existed at the time this bind was made.

This is different from `$('#content a').click(function(e)` or `$('#content a').on("click", function(e)` which both say "bind a click handler to `#content a`", the problem with this is that it cannot bind to a `#content a` that doesn't exist at the time this bind is made.

Comment: You're missing the `load()`

Comment: But if i refresh the page by F5, then every is gone where i just clicked on?

Comment: Although it's not really in scope of this question... I think I'd use a PHP session variable and update it for whatever page content is currently being viewed. This var could be updated on the PHP file that gets called in `load()`, then show whatever it's set to on initial load.. if it's not set, revert to some default page.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding the links after the document ready event has been completed.  The links do not get the event handler associated with them.  To get your links to work you want to  associate it with the document and use `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#content a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    location.hash = link;
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose we have the `.on`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#content a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    location.hash = link;
});
```

Comment: `#content` is the container, probably best to use `$("#content").on...`

Comment: But if i refresh the page by F5, then every is gone where i just clicked on?

Comment: @Yooouuri To preserve data between page loads you need to use something like cookies or data storage, it's not relevant to what you asked originally in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation

```
$('#content').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    location.hash = link;
});
```

when you add dynamic elements you must code for them using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)